# How to enable CORS requests for Bamboo API

Tags: bamboo

I would like to take advantage of the Bamboo APIs, but when I make requests from my client application, I get a CORS error (it seems to me that CORS requests should automatically be enabled for the Bamboo API). How can I allow my origin access to the Bamboo APIs? I've tried searching the administrative section of my Bamboo instance to find a place to add allowed origins, but I haven't found anything yet.